# Showing number of comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

Some questions are answered completely with comments. There is no "answer" given. For me the only way to find out if somebody needs help is by clicking through questions. For me it would be helpful to see how many comments are given already on the overview page.

Comment: Would high comment count or low comment count indicate to you a question that you're interested in or not? (I've seen dozens of comments with no resolution, dozens with resolution, one with no resolution, one with resolution. I don't think this is a useful number to know...) Anyway, if you see an answer given in comments, please leave a comment asking the answer to be migrated to an answer.

Comment: There is no real indication on whether a question has been answered correctly by the number of comments. But it shows me if somebody cares already.

Comment: True enough, a two-day-old question with no comments and no answers probably needs attention. (Though I've _also_ seen entire conversations in comments that were almost but not quite in English and completely _not_ about the question at hand...)

Comment: You are right it's not a clear indication. Same as the number of views. But I think it's helpful.

Comment: No, the added value is not worth the added clutter. Comments should not be "too" useful. If a comment answer the question it should be made an answer then accepted. Comments are usually posted to gather information needed to help.

Comment: This is pointless, there's absolutely no relationship between comments and the quality/resolution of the question. It just adds unnecessary clutter to the homepage. If you aren't interested in the question from the title and tags, don't open it. If you are, well then open it.